# Authorization and Authentication in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Iam using forms authentication in asp.net Application,i want to make pages accessible depending upon roles defined in database. for eg there are three rolesdefined in database salary admin, manager, Clerk. i want a page salary.aspx can be accessed only by salary admin and not any other roles.How to go about, your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using the ASP.NET membership provider is a good option. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx) is a link to a full walkthrough, and another nice link from [asp.net site](http://www.asp.net/moving-to-aspnet-20/tutorials/membership)

EDIT: just to get the details out the comments (adapted from MSDN):

```
<configuration>
   <location path="/somepage.aspx">
       <system.web>
            <authorization>
               <allow roles="SomeRole" />
               <deny users="*" />
            </authorization>
          </system.web>
        </location>
<configuration>
```

Comment: iam using AD memebershipprovider to authenticate user.. during authenticationis is necessary tht i shd create a cookie on client side. iam using this is web.config

Comment: <configuration>    
     <system.web>    
          <authorization>    
               <allownroles="Administrators","supervisors","salaryadmin" />    
               <deny users="*"/>    
          </authorization>    

     </system.web>

     <!-- Allow all users to visit salary.aspx -->    
     <location path="salary.aspx">    
          <system.web>    
               <authorization>                       <allow roles="salary Admin" />

Comment: </authorization>    
          </system.web>         </location>    </configuration>

Comment: i think the cookie is created by default , if you want cookieless mode you should specify it in the `forms tag`. to specify access to a page all you ned to do is more `location` tags i.e.  `<location path="login.aspx"> <system.web> <authorization> <allow users="?"/> </authorization> </system.web> </location>` see [MSND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx)

Comment: <location path="login.aspx"> <system.web> <authorization> <allow users="?"/> </authorization> </system.web> </location> allow anonymous access but i want a particular access particular page..  like salary.aspx can only be viewed by salary admin role

Comment: i have read a lot of stuff but now iam confused.. do i have to use website administration tool to add roles.. if yes wht if i want to get roles from sql.. as i have table defined. in sql.. and if iam specifying in location element allow roless.. how exactly specifying in in location file allow roles will help me.. if i have role Administrator.. how web config knows.. tht particular user has administratorrole and it access toparticular page should be denied.

Comment: with login page i will taking username with that i will be getting a role.. and iam using SQL membership.. if how exactly my sql retrieved role and web.config specifiedrole will communicate

Comment: the config file doesnt 'know' about roles, you need to maintain the config file based on the roles you have in the database.

Comment: 1) i was giving you an example. for your specific page, you can add: `<location path="salary.aspx"> <system.web> <authorization> <allow roles="salaryadmin" /> <deny users="*"/> </authorization> </system.web> </location>` 2)to get a list of a user's see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.getrolesforuser.aspx) you can use the roleprovider calss 3) the config file doesnt 'know' about roles, you need to maintain the config file based on the roles and users you have in the ASP.NET membership database.

Comment: if i have three roles in database  and i define three role in webconfig allowroles.. how exactly will they communicate.? u getting my question

Comment: ok that menas i will retrieve roles for a particular user through GetRolesForUser  method and config file will automatically detect it..

Comment: im sorry if i didnt understand what you mean, buy regarding your last commnet, the config file will not detect anything. its jus ta file. you need to type in the roles that exist in the database.

Comment: YESS  i will type in roles.. but after using role provider class.. it will be sync with database.. so if i have role salaryadmin of a particular user.. and in web.config file i have written roles <allow roles="salaryadmin"> so it will automatically detect that this role have to be given access to a particular file.